# Loading files with different names in MatLab

Tags: matlab, import, loading

I'm trying to read .vhdr files into MatLab in a loop function, but they all contain a different date in the filename. How can I get this to work? It's in the structure below where it starts with '01_' then has the subject number '####', then '*rest*' and then the date of collection '02202021' then the .vhdr filetype.

File name structure: '01_####_rest_02202021.vhdr'

I have defined my subject numbers above in a variable called subject.

```
subject = {'00001', '00002', '00003'}

EEG=poploadbv('C:/Users/M/Datasets',['01_',subject,'_Rest_','*.vhdr']);
```

I'm not that familiar with MatLab as I usually work in R, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple loop in matlab:

```
subject = {'00001', '00002', '00003'};

for ii=1:length(subject)
    curr_file = strcat('C:/Users/M/Datasets','01_',subject{ii},'_Rest_','*.vhdr');
    % EEG=poploadbv(curr_file);
    disp(curr_file);
end
```

I use the string concatenation function (`strcat()`) to put your path and file together. Semicolons at the end of lines will suppress the printing to screen (e.g. `subject = {'00001', '00002', '00003'};` with the semicolon will define subject but not print it)